# which method is more optimised?

Tags: vba

Well I have to create an xml file and write some tags to it.I have created the xml file like a normal creation of text file but with a .xml extension and using these statements

**First approach**

```
a.writeline("<root>")
if (check_boxapp.value = true ) then
   a.writeline("<condition>value</condition>")
end if
if (check_boxname.value = true ) then
   a.writeline("<condition>value1</condition>")
end if
```

like these and I have around 50 if statements.20 for < condition > tags and other 5 for someother tag and other 2 for naming tag.So i cannot go for a switch case statment. My question is does it slow down the execution of vba macro because for every if statment Im accessing the file.Im checking the condition and accessing the file , so does it slow down the performance. This is my first approach

**Second approach**

creating an array and keep track of the status of checkboxes in the array and then at the end, loop through the array, if it has 1 then use writeline else dont. something like

```
if chechk_box.value = true then
   a(i) = 1 
end if 

and at the end 

for i = 1 to 20 
       if(a(i)=1) then
          a.writeline("something")
       end if
next i
for i = 1 to 10 
       if(a(i)=1) then
          a.writeline("something")
       end if
next i
```

May be I guess i have around 6 loops.In these approach Iam creating an array and using the 50 if statments and then again the 6 for loops.I believe Creating an array, eats up the memory and also the code is little big compared to the first one and also a bit complicated to understand.

But I am not sure which one would the be the faster way to do. Please help with these or anyother smarter way is much appreciated

Comment: Have you benchmarked the two approaches yet?  That seems like the surest way to know.  Google "GetTickCount" for a reliable timing method for your benchmarking.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I wrote a few functions that could  be useful to you: http://idevlop.blogspot.com/search/label/xml

Comment: VBA does not have a "WriteLine" method so either this is pseudocode or you are using a different programming language. Which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a very small amount of I/O and worrying about write times seems to be an unnecessary concern as either approach should be in the low millisecond range.

Here is another approach you can take to keep things simple by enumerating the controls themselves;

```
'//checkbox example
Dim Ctrl As Control
For Each Ctrl In Me.Controls
    if TypeName(Ctrl) = "CheckBox" Then
        '//look at each checkbox
        '//you could use the controls .name to pull out its node value
        '//by using a naming convention like "chk_XML_NodeValue" + mid$(Ctrl.Name, 9)
        '//or by putting the node value in the Tag propery of the control (in the designer or code)
        if (Ctrl.value) then
            a.writeline "<condition>" & Ctrl.Tag & "</condition>"
        end if
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your file in memory using the MSXML object model, then dump the entire thing to disk using DOMDocument.Save. I assume VBA here -- you are using "WriteLine" in your example, but VBA does not have a "WriteLine" method.

Ex:

```
Dim xmlDoc As Object ' MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Dim pi As Object ' MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
Dim rootelem As Object ' MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
Dim valueNode As Object ' MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode

' create new MSXML Document
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")

' add XML declaration at top of file
Set pi = xmlDoc.createProcessingInstruction("xml", "version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'")
xmlDoc.appendChild pi

' create root element
Set rootelem = xmlDoc.createElement("root")
xmlDoc.appendChild rootelem

If check_boxapp.value then
  Set valueNode = xmlDoc.createElement("condition")
  valueNode.nodeTypedValue = "value"
  rootelem.appendChild valueNode
End If

If check_boxname.value then
  Set valueNode = xmlDoc.createElement("condition")
  valueNode.nodeTypedValue = "value1"
  rootelem.appendChild valueNode
End If

' save to disk
xmlDoc.Save "C:\MyFile.xml"
```

Now you have a valid XML file. It would be simple to adjust this code (using the code provided by Alex K) to loop through your checkboxes and write the XML out.